# Chaining citations in pandoc

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I use pandoc to convert a mardown file into latex. for that I am using the [@author_journal_year] format to grab citations automatically. But as far as I see there doesn't seem to be a way to tell latex to merge citations when needed. For instance if using subtext numbers, one would expect citations to appear as 1-3 instead of 123. Is there a way to tell pandoc to merge the citations into a single block?

Comment: Wouldn't that be done in the `.latex` template file? I.e., loading `natbib` or `biblatex` with the appropriate options?

Answer (score 0):

Using semicolons in between identifiers instead of writing them side by side does it eg:  [@author_journal_year; @author2_journal2_year2]